# I can't get clearInterval working :/

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I built my own slideshow for my own use and everything works fine. I've set up an interval, which brings up the different slides.

Now I'm trying to add the possbility to pause the interval on hover and continue it after leaving the slideshow div.

Do yo have any advice for me? Thanks

This is what i have right now:

```
function slideContent(div) {

    $('.contents').removeClass('act');

    if (div == 'first') {
        $('#stretchWidth').stop().animate({ "left": 0}, 700);
        $('.contents.first').addClass('act');
    } else if (div == 'second') {
        $('#stretchWidth').stop().animate({ "left": -700}, 700);
        $('.contents.second').addClass('act');
    } else if (div == 'third') {
        $('#stretchWidth').stop().animate({ "left": -1400}, 700);
        $('.contents.third').addClass('act');
    } else if (div == 'fourth') {
        $('#stretchWidth').stop().animate({ "left": -2100}, 700);       
        $('.contents.fourth').addClass('act');
    } else if (div == 'fifth') {
        $('#stretchWidth').stop().animate({ "left": -2800}, 700);       
        $('.contents.fifth').addClass('act');
    }
};




function slideContentAutomatic() {
    var $n;
    $n = 1;

    var run = function() { 

        switch($n) {
            case 0:
            slideContent('first')
            $n++;
            break;

            case 1:
            slideContent('second')
            $n++;
            break;

            case 2:
            slideContent('third')
            $n++;
            break;

            case 3:
            slideContent('fourth')
            $n++;
            break;

            case 4:
            slideContent('fifth')
            $n = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    $('#contentSlide').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(run);
    }, function(){
        setInterval(run, 4000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how you `clearInterval`

```
var x = setInterval(run, 4000); 

clearInterval(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

clearInterval should only accept a unique Interval ID which is created by setInterval. I recommend you to set a global varibale as IntervalID.

e.g.

```
var myIntervalId = null;
function slideContentAutomatic() {
    //..Your code..
    $('#contentSlide').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(myIntervalId);
    }, function(){
        setInterval(run, 4000);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.clearInterval